# Difference in Session States?

Tags: asp.net, session

Im developing locally and every time I re-build my app I annoying have to log back into the application. I have changed the web.config to use either sql or stateserver session state so that re-building should leave my session active. I used to do this with another app I worked on.

However whilst some of the session is staying alive its cleary not working properly as when I view the site things are well...wrong.

Any idea why simply chaging the way the session is stored and taking out of inproc in this case and removing it remotely is breaking what seems to be the sesiion on my app?

/////////////////

Okay all I have changed between the app working and not working is where the session is located. This should not affect anything should it? Session is session no matter how you look at it. Wrong is my way of saying that the app is working incorrectly just because I changed where the session is stored.

Comment: If your issue is that you are asked to authenticate again, that might be because Authentication and Session are two different things. Session is just a Cache that's exclusive on a per user basis. Clarify what do you mean by "Wrong"

Comment: Okay all I have changed between the app working and not working is where the session is located. This should not affect anything should it? Session is session no matter how you look at it. Wrong is my way of saying that the app is working incorrectly just because I changed where the session is stored.

Comment: @Pete2k well, as you know, if you change from InProc to StateServer or SqlStateServer the objects you store in session need to be serializable. Are you doing that? Did you decorate your objects with `[Serializable]`?

Comment: Ah no I didnt that would be it then! Okay any easy way around this you recokon? Shame I guess it makes sense though...., maybe you can answer and I will give you the crown on this one then :0)